# How to use bigcommerce api get json reponse using postman

Tags: c#, postman, bigcommerce

Hello I have a bigcommerce account and I want to get order list . How to get json response using postman and integrate using URL using jQuery ajax .

I have this information :

ACCESS TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxx

CLIENT ID: xxxxxxxxxx

CLIENT SECRET: xxxxxxxxxx

NAME: Brisk Sol
API PATH: https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v3/

I want to get orders list in postman I have use api path but got error:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "title": "Not found",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes",
    "errors": {}
}
```

Comment: That error is telling you the URL isn't a valid address, which seems to be the case.

Comment: I have generate this URL  from bigcommerce dashboard.@stuartd

Comment: bigcommerce generate this path and other details How to use this in postman . Kindly help me .@stuartd

Comment: I suggest you contact them, or look at their documentation, for the reason a request to a valid URL would return a 404 other than it not actually existing.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to make a request since you have not listed a resource endpoint. Have a look at the BigCommerce documentation for [making your first request](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/basics/making-requests) and that should get you started.

Comment: I'd add that if you want to get all orders, the URL path should be https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/4jwabif3gj/v2/orders